# Order of operations for dereference and bracket-ref in C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

If I do `*ptr[x]`, is that equivalent to `*(ptr[x])`, or `(*ptr)[x]`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`*(ptr[x])`

See the [Wikipedia operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages), or, for a more detailed table, [this C/C++ specific table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

Comment: that link doesn't mention pointer dereferencing... but it does say array access binds most tightly

Comment: The `*` is in the 2nd row of the table, after `[]` in the 1st row.

Comment: Ah, I see how this could be confusing, since `*` could mean multiplication or pointer dereference.  Multiplication goes after though, in row 3 of the table.

Comment: ah yes, reading comprehension for the win. i was scanning the text for mention of the word 'pointer' and didn't realize it's just a unary operation too.

Comment: Wikipedia also has a comprehensive C(++)-specific [precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks, incorporated this table into my post.

Comment: Yay, my favorite table. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence )

Answer (score 9):

In C, all postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operators, and prefix operators have higher precedence than infix operators.  So its `*(ptr[x])`

Answer (score -1):

Using the counter-clockwise movement of analyzing and parsing that simple example

```
1. starting with ptr, work in counter-clockwise until you hit asterisk operator
2. asterisk, in counter-clockwise until you hit subscript operator
3. we arrive here, at subscript operator [x]
```

Since `[]` has higher precedence than the asterisk as per this [table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) , that makes it `*(ptr[x])`

Comment: where does this counterclockwise method come from?

Comment: @Claudiu: It's a well known technique for parsing and analyzing C expressions...it is found in 'Expert C Programming - Peter Van der Linden', see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305255/pointer-array-syntax-char-p-pn-in-c-c

Comment: That's for parsing type specifiers and declarations. But in the question `*ptr[x]` is an expression, and so all you need to know is operator precedence.

Comment: So the counter-clockwise thing *doesn't* apply to expressions?  I would *strongly* drop mentioning that, as operator precedence is all that matters here.