# Passing char** into a function , doesn't change its values , or does it ? 

Tags: c, linux, arrays, ubuntu

I'm passing a dynamic allocated variables into a function , and after returning from that 
function , when I run inputs on the code , some of those inputs makes the program to crash .

As you can see , I test the `argv` array , twice , once at the end of `divide` , and another 
time after I return from `divide` . In the first check I get all the values of `argv` from 
index `0` to `argc`  , but in the `2nd` check (after returning from `divide` back into `main`)
index `0` make the `for` loop to crash .

So obviously I'm doing something wrong , any idea what ?

Comment: Huge block of code, we meet again....

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Indeed we are. You asked me to post the code , here it is :)

Comment: valgrind is your friend.

Comment: What does `divideAmpersandStrings(stringBeforeAmpersand , ampersandPtr);` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
argv =(char**) realloc(argv, (current+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

This is the likely culprit. Calling `realloc()` can allocate a new (presumably larger) block of memory into which the data from the old block is copied, and then deallocate the old block. The problem isn't that you're changing the value of `argv` in `main()`, it's that you're *not* changing it. You're deallocating the block that it points to without updating main()'s `argv` to point to the new block.

Comment: Good one! I'll check this ASAP

Comment: I've changed to prototype of `main` . It has nothing to do with the code , I could have just left a blank `main()` . So I guess this is not the problem ?

Comment: No, it's still the problem. You're still calling `realloc()` in your `divide()` function, and that still results in `argv` becoming a dangling pointer in `main()`, and you're still using that bad pointer in `main()`, and (I presume that) it's still crashing.

Comment: Okay ,of course you're right ,but how shall I fix it ? allocate that memory in `main` ?

Comment: The easiest fix is probably to pass the address of `argv` instead of the value: `divide(char *s , char *t , int *a , char*** argv , char d[])`. Then you can assign the new block: `*argv = realloc(*argv, (current+1)*sizeof(char*));`. This is the C equivalent of passing by reference.

Comment: But I'd need to change `argv` in `main` , am I wrong ? from `**` into `***` ? and the rest of the `main` ...

Comment: No, you'd keep main()'s `argv` just as it is, but pass it into `divide()` as `&argv`, which means "take the address of 'argv'". If this is new to you, pull out your C book and read about [passing by reference in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2229498/643383).

Comment: I've updated the original post . There's still a problem with the code after adding another `*` to the `argv` variable inside method `divide` . I'd appreciate if you could take a look . Thanks .

Comment: Please read up on pointers in C. You're doing `*argv[current]`, which is the same as `*(argv[current])`. You should instead say `(*argv)[current]`. See [Order of operations for dereference and bracket-ref in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3552844/643383).

Comment: +100 for your explanation ! I've been trying to work this bug for the past day . You're indeed awesome , my friend!