# Init a multidimensional-array-pointer ****

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, new-operator

I want to store pointers (Bar *) in a multidimensional-array of 2 dimensions. And I want to access to this array from a pointer.
So I want to initialize a **foo[][] (or ****fo).

```
Bar ****_bars; // declaration
int n, m; // dimensions size

_bars = new Bar ***;
*_bars = new Bar **[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    *_bars[i] = new Bar *[m];
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        *_bars[i][j] = new Bar();
    }
}
```

My app crash at line `*_bars[i][j] = new Bar();` when i=0 and j=1.

Comment: why not use vector<vector<bar*>> ?

Comment: `Bar ****_bars;` Wow the max stars question today, :-P!

Comment: `std::vector` is useless, my arrays are static.

Comment: @LucBerthiaume or alternatively [`std::array<std::array<bar*>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as long sizes are known at runtime. _@OP_ Check the link, how to handle static arrays properly in c++.

Comment: "std::vector is useless, my arrays are static." No it isn't, and no they're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely the precedence of the `[]` and `*` operators (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552844/order-of-operations-for-dereference-and-bracket-ref-in-c)). For example, in your case the expression `*_bars[i]` is evaluated like:

```
*(_bars[i]) = ....
```

Since there is only one element in `_bars[]` you run into "issues" with `_bars[1]`. Same thing with `*_bars[i][j]`.

But really, please use `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>` for something like this.