# malloc() causing crash with de-referenced 2-D character array in loop

Tags: c, arrays, windows, icc

Arrays is initialized as:

```
char** aldos = NULL;
char** aldoFilenames = NULL;
```

Function definition is:

```
int readFilesFromDirectory(char*** dest, char*** nameDest)
```

Passed to function via:

```
readFilesFromDirectory(&aldos, &aldoFilenames);
```

After counting the files, dest and nameDest are initialized:

```
*dest = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*count);
*nameDest = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*count);
count = 0; //resetting to read in the files again
```

First filename for nameDest is read in like:

```
*nameDest[count] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(findData.cFileName) + 1);
strcpy(*nameDest[count], findData.cFileName);
//can confirm in my program, the value exists properly in *nameDest[count]
count++;
```

Heres where the problem comes in, when I throw it in a loop, it crashes (with no real useful error codes):

```
while (FindNextFile(hfind, &findData) != 0) 
{
  *nameDest[count] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(findData.cFileName) + 1); //doesnt make it past here, CRASH
   sprintf(*nameDest[count],"%s\0",findData.cFileName);
   count++;
 }
```

Any insight would be appreciated, I'll be quick to add more information if requested

Comment: How is `count` initialized when `*dest` and `*nameDest` are assigned to?

Comment: @cad It is set by a snippet that counts the number of files, the value is correct, and there are 5 files

Comment: What is the value of `count` when it crashes?

Comment: @JohnB count = 1 prior to crash

Comment: The number of files in a directory can change in between you allocating the array and copying the names. Run the program in a debugger (ex. gdb or the visual studio debugger) to find out where it crashes.

Comment: Also I'm not sure of the order of operations of `*nameDest[count]`; it might be doing the index before the pointer deference. Try doing `(*nameDest)[count]`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo That fixed it, thanks, add as an answer please

Comment: suggest googling for 'three star programmer'

Comment: As `count` increases, the `dest` must be updated via a call to `realloc()` so there is enough allocated memory to hold the pointers to the individual file names

Comment: @user3629249 IMO the triple-star here is appropriate, since the function has an out parameter (first star) that writes to an array (second star) of strings (char and third star).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `*nameDest[count]`, [the indexing operator place before the dereference operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552844/order-of-operations-for-dereference-and-bracket-ref-in-c), making the code equivalent to `*(nameDest[count])`, which is not what you want since `nameDest` points to the array. You need to do the pointer dereference before the array indexing by using parenthesis: `(*nameDest)[count]`

I should also note that polling the OS twice for the directory listing - once for the count and once for the actual names - is unreliable, as between the two polls, the count might have changed. Consider using `realloc` to resize the array as you find more entries.

Comment: This is for a school assignment, were it production code I would do some of these optimizations, but for the purpose of the assignment we are allowed to assume nothing will change

Answer (score -1):

Several problems in the code

1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 and multiplying anything by 1 has no effect, especially as part of a malloc() parameter, so it just clutters the code and accomplishes nothing.

Suggest removing the `sizeof(char)` expressions.

2) the memory allocation family (malloc, calloc, realloc) have a returned type of `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer, so the cast is unneeded, just clutters the code and is a real headache when debugging and/or maintaining the code.

Suggest remove the casting of the returned values from malloc()

3) in C, array offsets start with 0 and end with array size -1  So when an array of size `count` is allocated, the valid offsets are 0...count-1.

However, the posted code is accessing array[count] which is past the end of the array, this is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: sizeof(char) expresses the intent of the original programmer, so there is no doubt of what the code does when a maintainer might question whether there is a sizeof missing in the allocation. Because the code is less consistent it is less readable.

Comment: It does not accomplish nothing, it accomplishes transparency and readability.

Comment: It is expected that the original programer and and maintenance programmers all know that the memory allocation functions, like `malloc()` have a parameter that is a count of bytes.   It is sort of like:  here is a number:  `25`,  that is perfectly well understood.   Now here is a number multiplied by 1 `1*25`.   Which is more readable?  Which is more understandable?  Additionally, when your code gets 'peer reviewed' at work, what will happen?  Answer: the code will get 'dinged' and an `action item` written to remove the superfluous expression: `sizeof( char )`

Comment: @user3629249 You haven't provided any arguments why is an integer constant value better. You also haven't addressed my and EyeOfTheHawks' arguments. Your two question, *Which is more readable? Which is more understandable?*, are addressed by the first two comments. Your last argument is an anecdote and thus is not an argument.

Comment: ??arguments??  I'm providing commentary not arguments.  As you should know, commentary often contains `best practices` and `common practice` information.  (like checking returned values from system functions for errors).   Why do you want an argument for/against `best practices`?  BTW: my comments are about clarity of the code, not about weather to use a variable or a constant as a parameter.

Comment: why the down votes?  This line: `*nameDest = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*count);` clearly says there are `count` pointers available (which can be indexed by 0...count-1) So, all lines that are referencing `*nameDest[count]` are accessing beyond the end of the array: Here is an example: `*nameDest[count] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(findData.cFileName) + 1);`