# Malloc'ing Arrays and then Free'ing them?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm currently messing around with c I'm having a few hiccups in the pointer usage and syntax area.

Below, i am (trying) to create an array of pointers to integer arrays, then, direct each pointer to an array created via malloc().

After the arrays have been created i then for loop through each cell, assigning a value.

Now, all of this seems to be working, but when it comes to then using free() to take back the memory, the program crashes.

I have noticed that if i malloc() the array memory and then immediately call free() on them, the program executes without problem. When however I malloc(), assign values and THEN call free() the crash will occur. (Segmentation fault).

Below is the code that works, malloc() then immediately free()ing

```
int (*ptrArr[5])[5];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    ptrArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    printf("ptrArr[%d][%x]->[%x]\n", i, &ptrArr[i], &*ptrArr[i]);
printf("\n");

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        printf("[%x](%2d) | ", &*ptrArr[i][j], *ptrArr[i][j]);  
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for(int i=4; i>=0; i--)
    free(ptrArr[i]);
```

the above executes as i expected it to, but when I assign values to cells and then try and call free afterwards, a segmentation fault is generated:

```
int (*ptrArr[5])[5];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    ptrArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    printf("ptrArr[%d][%x]->[%x]\n", i, &ptrArr[i], &*ptrArr[i]);
printf("\n");

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        printf("[%x](%2d) | ", &*ptrArr[i][j], *ptrArr[i][j]);  
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int loop = 5;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        *ptrArr[i][j] = (loop + (i*j));
        ++loop;
    }
}

printf("\n");
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        printf("[%x](%2d) | ", &*ptrArr[i][j], *ptrArr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for(int i=4; i>=0; i--)
{
    printf("Freeing ptrArr[%x]\n", i);
    free(ptrArr[i]);
}
```

I think I'm either misunderstanding the

```
int (*ptrArr[5])[5];
```

declaration, which I intended was an array of 5 pointers, each pointing to an integer array, or im not assigning values to cells correctly, instead, corrupting memory which causes the free() to fail.

Any help would be appreciated, I hope the question is clear and succinct.

Thanks.

Comment: `int *ptrArr[5]` is declaring array of 5 pointers.

Comment: I don't think that the first code works. Try it with a size bigger then 5, maybe 10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I approach this type of problem is to print out the `sizeof` the various suspects, like this

```
int (*test[5])[5];

printf( "%zu ", sizeof(test) );
printf( "%zu ", sizeof(test[0]) );
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(test[0][0]) );
```

The result is `40 8 20`. (Note that on my machine an `int` is 4 bytes and a pointer is 8 bytes.)
So that tells me that `test` is an array of 5 pointers. It logically follows that `test[0]` is a single pointer. But what's interesting is that `test[0][0]` is an array of 5 ints.

If I add the following line of code

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(test[0][0][0]) );
```

the output is 4, i.e. `test[0][0][0]` is a single `int`. From that we conclude that the declaration `int (*test[5])[5]` is declaring a three dimensional array, which is not what you intended.

---

So let's try a simpler declaration, like this

```
int (*test)[5];

printf( "%zu ", sizeof(test) );
printf( "%zu ", sizeof(test[0]) );
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(test[0][0]) );
```

The output is `8 20 4`, which is to say that `test` is a single pointer, `test[0]` is an array of 5 ints, and `test[0][0]` is a single `int`. We conclude that `int (*test)[5]` declares a two dimensional array.

---

The next question is how to we allocate memory for the array. If we do this

```
test = malloc( 5 * sizeof(int) );
```

then we have an array that has 1 row and 5 columns, basically a one-dimensional array.

To get a two-dimensional array with `N` rows, we need

```
test = malloc( N * 5 * sizeof(int) );
```

Then we can fill, print, and free the array like this

```
int N = 5;
for ( int row = 0; row < N; row++ )
    for ( int col = 0; col < 5; col++ )
        test[row][col] = (row+5)*10 + col;

for ( int row = 0; row < N; row++ )
{
    for ( int col = 0; col < 5; col++ )
        printf( "%2d ", test[row][col] );
    printf( "\n" );
}

free( test );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a headache to decode, but like a good cryptic crossword, there's a solution.  I've tidied things up a bit.  The fundamental problem was the dereferencing.

See:
[Order of operations for dereference and bracket-ref in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552844/order-of-operations-for-dereference-and-bracket-ref-in-c)

I've marked the line in some working code below.  I've added brackets around the (*ptrArr[i]) to obtain the array, that can then be correctly indexed as (*ptrArr[i])[j].

I've also suggested an alternative way of declaring the array in the first place.  One that's easier to verify!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5 

int main()
{
    // This makes things clearer :-
    typedef int ArrayType[SIZE];
    typedef ArrayType * ArrayPtr;
    ArrayPtr ptrArr[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        ptrArr[i] = malloc (sizeof (int) * SIZE);

    int loop = SIZE;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            // THIS NEXT LINE HAD THE WRONG BRACKETS IN
            // *(ptrArr[i])[j] = (loop + (i * j));
            (*ptrArr[i])[j] = (loop + (i * j));
            printf("array has base address: %lx\n", ptrArr[i]); 
            printf("writing to: %lx\n", &(*ptrArr[i])[j]); 
            ++loop;
        }
    }

    for (int i = SIZE-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf ("Freeing ptrArr[%x] with address %lx\n", i, ptrArr[i]);
        free (ptrArr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    ptrArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

This says that `ptrArr[i]` is a pointer to some integers.

```
    *ptrArr[i][j] = (loop + (i*j));
```

This says that `ptrArr[i][j]` is a pointer to an integer.

Which is it? These two pieces of code differ in the number of layers of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is not correct, because you are printing the incorrect array indexes.

The nested for loop calls this:

```
printf("[%x](%2d) | ", &*ptrArr[i][j], *ptrArr[i][j]);
```

The third parameter is identical to `ptrArr[i][j][0]`.

But that is incorrect. It should be `ptrArr[i][0][j]` because you allocated only one inner dimension of your 2d array with the malloc call: `ptrArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);`.

You see `int (*ptrArr[5])[5];` is really an array of pointers to an array of 5 ints. And `ptrArr[i]` is a pointer to an array of 5 ints.

This also means that the second parameter, `&*ptrArr[i][j]`, which is identical to `ptrArr[i][j]` should really be `ptrArr[i][0]`, because again, we only have one dimension allocated.

...

We're almost done. First replace the malloc call with calloc, so we won't print garbage values. Then replace %x printf specifiers with %p and cast their respective parameters to (void*).

With those corrections in place, the first example prints out the correct addresses and correct values, and doesn't have undefined behavior.(You can also remove redundant `&*` pairs)

(This has been just a fix for your first example! I haven't even addressed the second one. But the solution is mostly the same. )