# C Printing same array produces different results using two methods

Tags: c, pointers

I'm experimenting with C void functions and strings. I've tried this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(char** test);
int main(){
    char* test = "abcdef";
    print(&test);
    return 0;
}
void print(char** test){
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(*test);i++)
        printf("%c\n",*test[i]);
}
```

It prints for me the first `a A �` then segmentation fault. But after changing `*test[i]` to `*(*test+i)` which is pretty much the same thing it works for me as expected.

Is there any subtle difference `*test[i]` and `*(*test+i)` if not, why my code works in second examples meanwhile it doesn't in the first ?

Comment: This is an [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) problem. The array-index operator `[]` have higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`. Something a [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have told you (IMO).

Comment: Also "pretty much the same thing" is *not* "*exactly* the same thing". In fact, the two expressions you think are "pretty much the same thing" are *not*. (See my previous comment for why).

Comment: So to fix this can I do `(*test)[i]` ?

Comment: Yes that will do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of operations for dereference and bracket-ref in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552844/order-of-operations-for-dereference-and-bracket-ref-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is a `char**`. As *Some programmer dude* commented, the `[]` takes precedence over the `*` so your for loop is executed like this:

1. `*test[0] == *(test[0]) == 'a'`
2. `*test[1]` == `*(test[1])` == *(*some other address that is saved in memory after `&test`*) => UB

Either use one indirection in the whole program (i.e. *, not ** and `&test`), or use `(*test)[i]`