# Creating an array of null-terminated string arrays, where most string arrays are static

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, null-terminated

I'm trying to create an array of null-terminated string arrays. Everything in the array is known at compile time, except one element which is placed into it at runtime.

This is how I want the array to look:
`[ ["command1", "arg", "arg", 0], ["command2", 0], argv, ["command3", "arg", 0] ]`

So here command1, command2 and their args are known at compile time, only argv is placed into it at runtime.

The problem is that I can't make the this work. Currently I am doing this to create an array with NUM_COMMANDS (number) commands:

```
char *commands[ NUM_COMMANDS ][] = {
    {"command1", "arg", 0}, 
    {0}, /*This is where I want to place argv*/
    {"command2", "arg", 0}
    };
```

But it won't allow me to insert argv.

How can I change this into the kind of array I'm after?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't read through it yet, but this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305255/pointer-array-syntax-char-p-pn-in-c-c

Comment: You might need to add more information, like what is `NUM_COMMANDS`, and how you try to "insert" `argv`.

Comment: (And the compiler error message.)

Comment: That's because your `commands` is a constant value. You need to allocate memory dynamically. Something like: `char *commands_d[NUM_COMMANDS]; for(int i = 0; i < NUM_COMMANDS; i++) commands_d[i] = commands[i]; commands[2] = argv;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself after reading the link to the question roliu posted.

```
char **commands[ NUM_COMMANDS ];
char *command1[] = {"command1", 0};
char *command2[] = {"command2", "arg", 0};

argv[0] = "grep";

commands[0] = (char **) command1;
commands[1] = (char **) argv;
commands[2] = (char **) command2;
```

Thanks for the comments to the original question!